# Start-OBRegistration Vault credentials validation failed

Tags: azure, powershell, backup

I'm trying to register Windows client machine to a Azure Recovery Services Vault with a powershell script.

I'm having this error:

```
WARNING: Vault credentials validation failed.
Start-OBRegistration : Vault credentials file provided has expired. We recommend you download a new vault credentials file from the portal and use it within 2 days.
```

These are my commands:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname aly20-srv.xxx.onmicrosoft.com -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddHours(8)
$certificate =[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.RawData)

$Vault1 = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault –Name "rsvault-staging"
$CredsPath = "C:\temp"
$CredsFilename = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVaultSettingsFile -Backup -Vault $Vault1 -Path $CredsPath -Certificate $certificate

Import-Module -Name 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\bin\Modules\MSOnlineBackup'
Start-OBRegistration -VaultCredentials $CredsFilename.FilePath -Confirm:$false
```

It seems that the vault credentials file created in "C:\temp" is not valid.
If I try to get it directly from azure portal and run "Start-OBRegistration" command it works.

What's the problem? How can I solve?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using "-NotAfter (Get-Date).AddHours(8)"

This will make your certificate expire after 8 hours, the default is 1 year.

Comment: I can remove "NotAfter" param but nothing change. Same error.